# Get User id from class based view

Tags: python, django, class, view

I have a class based view:

```
class PostListViewMojeReported(ListView):

    def get_username(self, **kwargs):
        login_username = request.user.username
        context = {'login_username': login_username}
        return context

    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/filter_moje_reported.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(Q(status='Otvorena') & (Q(res_person_1_username=username) | Q(res_person_2_username=username)))
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 30
```

I don't know how to get username from the current logged in user to use as a filter in my queryset. I need to compare the current logged in user with 'res_person_1_username' and 'res_person_2_username'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the requerst object with `self.request`, so:

```
class PostListViewMojeReported(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/filter_moje_reported.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 30

    def get_username(self, **kwargs):
        login_username = self.request.user.username
        context = {'login_username': login_username}
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.request.user.username
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
           Q(res_person_1_username=username) | Q(res_person_2_username=username),
           status='Otvorena'
        ).order_by('-date_posted')
```

I would however advise to work with two `ForeignKey`s to the user model, and *not* store the username, since it is possible that later the user removes their account, and another person then creates an account with that username.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked flawlesssly. And for the advice.